# Need game piece to auto-deselect after moving

Tags: game-engine

I need a selected game piece to be automatically deselected after being moved, (as opposed to being deselected when selecting the next piece.)

[Current Script](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23905747/)

The reason I need this change is because: after a piece is moved, it will move again, and again, as many times as a new tile is selected. If a player tries to rotate the board and does not click completely off the board in empty space to deselect, then the piece moves when it shouldn't.

Comment: How do you select?

Comment: @Monster added pastebin to question.

Answer (score 0):

To line 46 add the lines (indented to match line):

```
deselect_piece(cont.owner['activeTile'])
cont.owner['activeTile'] = None
```

Comment: You need a deselect_piece() that accepts a piece rather than a controller. The second line manipulates the selected tile rather than the piece.

Comment: I can't get this to work. I've indented it and unindented it every way I can think of. Either nothing happens at all, or I lose my mouse. It does seem like (as Monster suggests,) that there needs to be and `cont.owner['activePiece'] = None` in there somewhere. I'm going to add some detail to the question.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly modified version of sdfgeoff's answer:

line 46

```
deselect_piece(cont)
```

Remarks:

- It is a bit confusing that selected items are called "active" I suggest to use the term "selected", or talk about activation/deactivation
- I do not see an option that is "selecting the next piece".
- I would use a mouse over (any) sensor that calls "run". It performs object detection already, making your code more focused (when mouse click and mouse over are positive, the user clicked on an object).